# SharePoint 2013 community site comments order

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to set the default comments order to be "newest" in a SharePoint community site for each thread?

Answer (score 0):

so, i found an answer
i edited a "theme.aspx" through spd, fieldref name="created" ascending="true" changed to "false"
that's it, so easy